# Поочередность SQL транзакций

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, транзакции

Использую MYSQLi.Есть такая проблема, при выполнении SQL транзакций иногда появляется ошибка: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Ошибка появляется потому что при выполнении одной транзакции запускается другая и нет доступа к некоторым таблицам, которые были заблокированы первой транзакцией.

Вопрос, можно ли как то организовать поочередное выполнение SQL транзакций? К примеру, если во время выполнения первой транзакции будет нужно выполнять вторую, что бы она не началась выполняться, пока не закончится первая?

Comment: Запросто... ставишь уровень изоляции SERIALIZABLE.

Comment: deadlock просто из за накладывания транзаций не происходит. вторая транзакция просто подождет первую и потом отработает. Деадлоки возникают только в случае не правильного блокирования. Надо пострjить работу приложения так, что бы записи блокировались всеми транзакциями в одном порядке. Если транзакция 1 заблокирует что то в таблице A, в это время начнется транзакция 2, блокирующая таблицу Б, а после нее таблицу А, то она будет ждать окончания 1 удерживая блок Б и если в это время транзакция 1 захочет взять блок Б, то возникнет деадлок

Comment: Akina, да я то использую SERIALIZABLE. Но когда количество транзакций возрастает, у меня появляется ошибка Deadlock. Не могу понять почему.

Comment: Mike, то есть мне нужно на все транзакции использовать уровень изоляции SERIALIZABLE? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: *когда количество транзакций возрастает, у меня появляется ошибка Deadlock. Не могу понять почему.* Mike же вроде вменяемо описАл причину - несогласованный порядок блокирования ресурсов в параллельных транзакциях.